# Cannot Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a big problem. While am opening Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it appears me an error:

"Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application"

I was searching solutions in Internet but I didn't found anything helpful.

I have SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Some suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: If this error caused just on opening not connecting to DB it seams that SSMS realy needs to be reinstalled

Comment: If I reinstall it the batabase and every configurations will be lost. Is there any other solution?

Comment: No, cause Management Studio is just a client to connect Sql Server|Sql Server Compact|Azure Sql maybe etc. It doesn't depends on your local Sql Server. Management Studio is also using as a remote manager, so it cannot harm you Sql Server

Comment: **What worked for me**: Reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio Isolated shell 2010 from [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1366), and then apply _Visual Studio 2010 SP1_.

Comment: Reinstalling only the isolated shell helped me too... I recently uninstalled the old visual studio (with the shell), that's what caused SSMS to fail on start. This question was mismarked as "unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: Faced this problem today, and a reinstall of the isolated shell did the trick. Found a working download at the [older-downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/) section of visualstudio.microsoft.com.